# Area 51 » Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: bug, area-51

I try to connect to Area 51 with my Google account, but I can't, it show me this error:

[image: Error Area 51]

> Now after some try I can connect.
>
> **> This does not happen just with Area 51, but also on Stack Overflow, many
>   times.**
>
> **> My friend, who uses the same network with me, also get this error**

Comment: You already have [an account there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/155217/youcef-laidani), and you were "seen" 2 minutes ago. Sure you're not already logged in?

Comment: Now i'm connected @ShadowWizard but after many try

Comment: Can't reproduce... I could login in a single try.

Comment: mm, maybe for you @S.L.Barth, but i don't know why this happen to me every times

Comment: @S.L.Barth as 99.999% of the users, most likely, otherwise the meta sites would have been flooded with bug reports. :)

Comment: I'm moving to leave this open. There is no evidence that the user is *not* still experiencing this problem, and it's quite possible that they still may be given the age of Area 51.

Comment: @Sonic agreed, and changed to [tag:bug]. Dev can take a look and add [tag:status-norepro] tag.